# Why all my HTML elements got my Object.prototype function as zattribute

Tags: javascript, html, object, attributes, prototype

I ve just learned how to make Object prototype function and my problem is when i call this function on any element, all my HTML elements got this function inside attribute. for example

```
Object.prototype.alertId = function(){
   alert(this.id);
}
```

so i call it

```
document.getElementById('bt').alertId();
```

and all my elements on the page look like this one

```
<div class="nfbpzpc" alertId="function(){alert(this.id);}"></div>
```

can you tell me what am doing wrong here

**UPDATE: I found whats the problem**

prototype function should start with HTMLElement if you work with html objects

```
HTMLElement.prototype.alertId = function(){
    alert(this.id);
}
```

Comment: what you want to implement ? found solution?